# Django forms inheritance doesn't read value from field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have 2 similars forms so I decide to inherite one form from another and it looks like:

```
class EditModuleForm(forms.Form):
    category_name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100)
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Icon', required=False)

    def clean_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get('image', None)
        if image:
            check_image_size(image)


class NewCategoryForm(EditModuleForm):
    category_slug = forms.CharField(label="Slug", max_length=10)
    field_order = ['category_name', 'category_slug', 'image']

    def clean_image(self):
        super(NewCategoryForm, self).clean_image()
```

and during using `NewCategoryForm` image is not validated and value is None. Looks like this form can't get value from image field. Could somebody give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `check_image_size` function return or do?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it raises ValidationError if size of image is too big

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning the cleaned data from your `clean_image` method, the `clean_<field>` methods allow us to change the data for the field and hence we *must* return the data from the method. Also you don't need to override the method inside your subclass:

```
class EditModuleForm(forms.Form):
    category_name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100)
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Icon', required=False)

    def clean_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get('image', None)
        if image:
            check_image_size(image)
        return image


class NewCategoryForm(EditModuleForm):
    category_slug = forms.CharField(label="Slug", max_length=10)
    field_order = ['category_name', 'category_slug', 'image']
```

Comment: the problem is if I print `image` in clean_image method while submiting NewCategoryForm, this value is empty like `self.cleaned_data.get....` returns None

Comment: @Frendom well have you set `enctype='multipart/form-data'` on your form tag (in the template)?

Comment: yes, before I recode my forms it was wortking and yeah, enctype is set